# Displaying image/jpeg file received from Ajax-Response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, base64

In my frontend application, I am receiving an image file (content-type: **image/jpeg**) directly as a response-body to my GET-ajax-request from the backend. I now want to simply display this image in an image control in my xml view.

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions! Happy to provide any other required information to help

What I've been trying so far, is to create a file from the response data and then transform this into a url for the image control:

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          responseType: "blob",
          success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");

            if (contentType === "image/jpeg") {
              var oReader = new FileReader();
              oReader.onload = function (e) {
                var sDataUrl = e.target.result;
                oImageControl.setSrc(sDataUrl);
                oImageControl.setVisible(true);
              };

              var file = new File([data], "imagefile.jpeg", {
                type: "image/jpeg"});

              oReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } 
          }
      });
```

The produced sDataUrl starts like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABBKRklGA.....`

My problem: the image control does not display anything. I don't get any error message.

For reference, I adapted this from elsewhere in my code, where I am **successfully** using a similar approach to display an image file that is not received via a response but read in using a **FileUploader**.
This works fine:

```
handleValueChange: function (oEvent) {
        this.file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
        var oImageControl = this.getView().byId("imageID");

        if (this.file && this.file.type === "image/jpeg") {
          var oReader = new FileReader();
          oReader.onload = function (e) {
            var sDataUrl = e.target.result;
            oImageControl.setSrc(sDataUrl);
            oImageControl.setVisible(true);
          };
          oReader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
        } 
}
```

Here, the created URL is of the form: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEBLAEsAA....`